# Padding SECOND OCCURANCE of numbers in hundreds of files

Tags: regex, perl

I've got hundreds files that are named with the following scheme:

XX - YY Title.ext

However, they don't always sort properly because XX and YY can be 1 or 2 digit numbers. I would like to rename the files such that XX and YY are always 2 digits by adding a leading zero if necessary.

For example, I'm currently getting sorting that looks like this:

```
1 - 1 BillyBob.ext   
1 - 10 Jimmy2.ext  
1 - 2 Stewy3.ext  
10 - 1 Cletus.ext     
2 - 1 Homer.ext
```

What I want is this:

```
01 - 01 BillyBob.ext
01 - 02 Stewy3.ext
01 - 10 Jimmy2.ext
02 - 01 Homer.ext
10 - 01 Cletus.ext
```

I've successfully changed the XX part using the code:

```
rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d", $&)/e' *
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to property execute something that will act on the YY part.

****Appended to orignial post****

More specifically, I don't know how to act on the YY part without also acting on any numeric charters that appear later in the filename.

****End appended content****

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: hmm... Windows's Explorer ("My Computer") actually sorts those names in the order you want, so what is it that isn't sorting it correctly for you? If you mean Perl's `sort`, then it's simply a matter of using Sort::Key::Natural's `natsort` instead of the builtin `sort`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `/g` on your substitution operator. Without it, the Perl just changes the first regex match in the string.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  s/\d+/sprintf('%02d', $&)/eg;
  print;
}

__DATA__
1 - 1 BillyBob.ext
1 - 10 Jimmy.ext
1 - 2 Stewy.ext
10 - 1 Cletus.ext
2 - 1 Homer.ext
```

Output:

```
01 - 01 BillyBob.ext
01 - 10 Jimmy.ext
01 - 02 Stewy.ext
10 - 01 Cletus.ext
02 - 01 Homer.ext
```

**Update:** To deal with the new requirement that you've added to your question, we'd need to make the regex more explicit. In this fix, I'm looking for two sets of digits separated by a dash. I capture the two sets of digits (which puts them in `$1` and `$2`) and expand them in the righthand side of the substitution operator.

The only line I needed to change was the one containing the substitution. It now looks like this:

```
s/(\d+) - (\d+)/sprintf('%02d - %02d', $1, $2)/e;
```

(And, as we're only making a single substitution here, we can lose the `/g` option.)

Comment: the output is not sorted as the OP expected

Comment: @stack0114106: The OP asked to rename the files. He knows how to sort the results.

Comment: Good call on the "global" operator.  However, what I failed to mention in my original post is that some of the "names" in my filenames also contain numeric characters.  If I process it globably, it makes the sorting work.  But, any other numeric characters get clobbered as well.  I've updated the orignal post to reflect this previously unstated condition.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness: this can also be solved directly on the (UNIX) shell with the `sort` from GNU coreutils:

```sh
$ cat dummy.txt
1 - 1 BillyBob.ext
1 - 10 Jimmy.ext
1 - 2 Stewy.ext
10 - 1 Cletus.ext
2 - 1 Homer.ext

$ sort --field-separator=- -k 1n -k 2n <dummy.txt
1 - 1 BillyBob.ext
1 - 2 Stewy.ext
1 - 10 Jimmy.ext
2 - 1 Homer.ext
10 - 1 Cletus.ext
```

i.e.

- use `-` as field separator,
- sort by first field numerically, and
- sort by second field numerically

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl one-liner

```
perl -lne ' s/(\d+)\s-\s(\d+)\s+(\S+)/sprintf("%02d-%02d %s",$1,$2,$3)/ge; $kv{$_}=1 ; END { print join("\n",sort keys %kv) } '
```

with inputs

```
$ cat notorious.txt
1 - 1 BillyBob.ext
1 - 10 Jimmy.ext
1 - 2 Stewy.ext
10 - 1 Cletus.ext
2 - 1 Homer.ext

$ perl -lne ' s/(\d+)\s-\s(\d+)\s+(\S+)/sprintf("%02d-%02d %s",$1,$2,$3)/ge; $kv{$_}=1 ; END { print join("\n",sort keys %kv) } ' notorious.txt
01-01 BillyBob.ext
01-02 Stewy.ext
01-10 Jimmy.ext
02-01 Homer.ext
10-01 Cletus.ext

$
```